# .NET 4.0 Framework Upgrade Requirements?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

What are the requirements for the upcoming .NET 4 release? Searched around for this and couldn't seem to find a definitive answer. Specifically...

1. Will clients have to upgrade their .NET Framework CLR (like from 1.1 to 2.0) to run 4.0-targeted applications?
2. Will ASP.NET require a framework upgrade or will behavior be similar to 2.0 running 3.5 apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will clients have to upgrade their .NET Framework CLR (like from 1.1 to
>   2.0) to run 4.0-targeted applications?

Yes, provided you target .NET 4.0 which has a new CLR version. However, you can target pre-4.0 frameworks to avoid this and run with the previous CLR version.

Check out Scott Guthrie's blog post: [Multi-Targeting Support (VS 2010 and .NET 4 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx).

In that post Scott targets the .NET 2.0 and midway through the post there's a screenshot showing ASP.NET running on 2.0 and he writes:

> When we run the application using the
>   built-in VS web-server, it will run
>   using the ASP.NET 2.0 version (and the
>   VS 2010 debugger will debug the CLR
>   2.0 process)

The post ends with targeting .NET 4.0 and a similar screenshot showing ASP.NET running on 4.0.

> Will ASP.NET require a framework upgrade or will behavior be similar to
>   2.0 running 3.5 apps?

Scott's post above covers this. Again, it depends on what you target.

In addition, the [Multi-Targeting section of the ASP.NET 4.0 whitepaper](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet40/#_TOC1_11) mentions the ability to use the new ASP.NET 4.0 targetFramework attribute in the Web.config compilation element: `<compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>`. If you omit it then the target framework is inferred. However, there are other considerations to targeting a framework, for example:

> In a .NET Framework 4 application
>   pool, the ASP.NET build system assumes
>   the .NET Framework 4 as a target if
>   the Web.config file does not include
>   the targetFramework attribute or if
>   the Web.config file is missing. (You
>   might have to make coding changes to
>   your application to make it run under
>   the .NET Framework 4.)

For more considerations visit the aforementioned link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know

1. Yes, They will. If you are developing with VS2010 then they will need to.
2. No idea :)

The system requirements can be found on [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ee2118cc-51cd-46ad-ab17-af6fff7538c9&displaylang=en#Requirements) page.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that for webapps they will need to be upgraded.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478%28VS.100%29.aspx

There are so many changes in .NET Framework 4 that I don't see how you can write code in 3.5 and not be running into the new features.  If you are developing an application with VS2010, then doing this update just makes sense to me.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409230%28VS.100%29.aspx